# Nginx Gunicon Dash (Flask) App seems to cache results somewhere (where??)

Tags: shell, docker, nginx, gunicorn, plotly-dash

I set up a dash app to visualize the [development of COVID-19 Infections in Germany](http://www.corona.fabianbosler.de) over time on a Google virtual machine running Ubuntu 18.04.

The app is based on three docker container:

1. The app itself served by gunicorn (on Port 5000)
2. NGINX container (does the translation from 80 -> 443 -> 5000)
3. Certbot container (to acquire and renew SSL certificates)

Now my problem is, no matter what I do, the app I get served is a fairly outdated version of the app (data exactly as when I first deployed it. Up until March 28). I tried changing the source data to include newer, but also to include fewer data and did not see any change whatsoever. I also tried changing the Nginx-settings around proxy_buffers, proxy_buffer_size, proxy_buffering, but to no avail.

This leads me to believe that I am getting served a cached app. I tried different browser/machines/devices which leads me to believe that the caching happens server-side.

I am not very familiar with Nginx nor Gunicorn nor Dash for that matter. But what I find very strange is that the results seemed to be cashed, even after `docker-compose up` and `down` multiple times.

What am I missing here?

Find the repo [here](https://github.com/FBosler/COVID-19-CONTAINERDEPLOY):

based on the following `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./services/web
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
    expose:
      - 5000

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - web
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be because the web [Dockerfile](https://github.com/FBosler/COVID-19-CONTAINERDEPLOY/blob/master/services/web/Dockerfile) runs a COPY command to copy in that entire directory, including `data.csv`.

Therefor if you place a new `data.csv` in that directory on the host, it would only be copied into the image if you do `docker-compose build`.

You could probably fix this by adding a volume mount to the `web` service, and place `data.csv` in there, allowing you to update that file on the host, then issue a `docker-compose restart web`.

To avoid having to issue that restart command, you'd probably have to change the way [this part](https://github.com/FBosler/COVID-19-CONTAINERDEPLOY/blob/b5afdae0a0120431d9aefb10d8a442405eeedd92/services/web/app.py#L41-L47) is coded:

```
def load_data():
    global data
    _ = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../data.csv'))
    return _

data = load_data()
```

Let me know if you need further advice on this.

Comment: You are amazing! I guess sometimes you just simply look for the totally wrong thing and miss the obvious (like having to rebuild your image or mounting the data). Thank you!

Comment: @FabianBosler Second set of eyes is never a bad thing :-)

Comment: while you are here, and a totally unrelated topic. Previously I had only worked with single docker container, I uploaded them to a registry then and would pull them on the target machine. Now, does that still work with docker-compose? From my understanding docker-compose will upload to docker-hub and not my own registry, right? Cheers, btw. would love to add you as a contact somewhere :) my contact data can be found here https://medium.com/@fabianbosler

Comment: @FabianBosler I'd posted some updates here, but it got a bit long, so will log an issue against your repo shortly to answer these further questions :-)